# Obtener el último match de la expresion regular

Tags: regex, match

Mediante una expresion regular, tengo que obtener todos los "guiones" de un string excepto el últiom
Por ejemplo tengo este string:

12a34-273EL45-348F56-4567

Debería quedar así:

12a34273EL45348F56-4567

Quise utilizar esta expresion
[image: Definicion de la expresion regular]

Y adaptarla a lo mío

intenté ingresando lo siguiente: /**(?+1).+(-)**/ Pero no encuentra lo que necesito
[image: test expresion regular]

¿Qué me está faltando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estoy seguro de que mi solucion se puede mejorar, basicamente atrapo lo que hay entre guiones y lo agrego a la salida, agregando un guion antes del ultimo grupo capturado.

[image: diagrama de la expresion regular]

Expresion regular: `^([A-Za-z\d]+)\-([A-Za-z\d]+)\-([A-Za-z\d]+)\-([A-Za-z\d]+)$`

Expresion de substitucion: `$1$2$3-$4`

Esto funciona debido a que cada cosa entre parentesis es un grupo y todos se enumeran

[image: grupos de captura]

usando el simbolo de pesos es que referenciamos a cada grupo por su numero en la expresion de remplazo.